# Timeout Exception in SQL server while bulk insertion data in SQL server from c#

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I am converting datatable to Xml in C# code as this code give me flexibility.
In SQL i convert XML to datatable and then inserting into my transaction table.
For less then 500 rows it is working proerply but for more then 500 records time out exception is coming.

```
Declare @pINPUT_STRING Xml = '<Row>      <SNo>1</SNo>      <Date>18-08-2019</Date>      <Voucher_No>156422</Voucher_No>      <From_Branch>HO-S-PO 8534</From_Branch>      <Main_Product>CGD-S-PVO 2130</Main_Product>      <Product>AMAZON SPEAKER G19ECHO DOT 3RD GEN (GREY)</Product>      <Serial_No>1</Serial_No>      <Receivable_Quantity>Audio</Receivable_Quantity>      <Penidng_Quantity>1</Penidng_Quantity>      <Remarks>1</Remarks>    </Row>';

SELECT * INTO #TEMP_GT FROM DBO.[FN_LOOKUP_GODOWN_TRANSFER](@pINPUT_STRING) FGT --Issue In This Row Timeout Exception

DECLARE @Inserted_total_count int = (SELECT Count(*)FROM #TEMP_GT FGT  LEFT JOIN LOOKUP_GODOWN_TRANSFER LGT ON FGT.Voucher_No=LGT.VOUCHER_NO AND FGT.Product=LGT.PRODUCT AND FGT.Serial_No=LGT.SERIAL_NO Where ISNULL(LGT.VOUCHER_NO,'') = '')

DECLARE @totalcount INT =0;
SET @totalcount = 0; (SELECT Count(*) from #TEMP_GT)

INSERT INTO LOOKUP_GODOWN_TRANSFER
    (DATE,VOUCHER_NO,BRANCH,FROM_BRANCH,MAIN_PRODUCT,PRODUCT,SERIAL_NO,RECEIVABLE_QTY,PENDING_QTY,REMARK,CREATED_BY,CREATED_ON,
    MODIFIED_ON,MODIFIED_BY,SERVER_LOGTIME,WAREHOUSE_ID,IS_ACTIVE)
SELECT 
    convert(varchar, convert(date, FGT.Date, 105), 101) as Date,FGT.Voucher_No,FGT.Branch,FGT.From_Branch,FGT.Main_Product,FGT.Product,
    FGT.Serial_No,CAST(FGT.Receivable_Quantity as int),FGT.Penidng_Quantity,FGT.Remarks,     
    FGT.CREATED_BY,  
    GETDATE(),
    GETDATE(),
    FGT.CREATED_BY,
    dbo.SNCLOCK(),
    FGT.WAREHOUSE_ID
    ,1 
FROM 
    #TEMP_GT FGT --DBO.[FN_LOOKUP_GODOWN_TRANSFER](@pINPUT_STRING) FGT
    LEFT JOIN LOOKUP_GODOWN_TRANSFER LGT ON FGT.Voucher_No=LGT.VOUCHER_NO AND FGT.Product=LGT.PRODUCT AND FGT.Serial_No=LGT.SERIAL_NO
Where 
    ISNULL(LGT.VOUCHER_NO,'') = ''
```

Any idea what can i use as the alternative way to bulk insert in database from c#

Comment: Consider passing rows as a [table-valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine) instead of XML. That will be much faster than parsing XML in T-SQL.

Comment: Also, you can pass a DataTable as the TVP parameter value so code changes should be minor.

Comment: Why do not use System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy? Works like a charm.